# Load documentclass from web

Tags: document-classes, input

I'm writing a documentclass to create a standard layout for all documents created by me and my co-workers.
Now, every time I make a change in the configurations I have to change the class for every project in their respective folders.

I want to build a single Documentclass that once I upgrade it all projects will be upgraded, be it by automatically loading from the web or by downloading it.

Anyone here ever did this? Is it possible?

What I tried till now is this:

`\immediate\write18{\unexpanded{https://drive.google.com/open?id=0B1emM}}`

But it didn't work.

Comment: it's best to just sync the file externally either by using some code repository like github, or a file share service like dropbox or google drive. You could put commands in write18 (it would have to be a _command_ not just a url) but then you need some cross platform downloader such as wget and have to run every document with shell-escape enables which isn't advisable.

Comment: It sound like there is a copy of your class in every project folder. In that case, first, configure a local `texmf` tree on your and your co-workers computers and move your class to a folder there (e.g. `texmf/tex/latex/company/`). You can also put graphics like logos or backgrounds in this folder. Then you could make the local `texmf` the working copy of a code repository. The latter can be configured to send an e-mail for new commits to all involved. And there are easy to use tools, so your co-workers can do the update on thier own.

Comment: Now if you and your coworker were on a LAN with file sharing, you could put the actual guts of the code into a tex file and \input it each time.